# Jasmine waiting for async function inside the tested function

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test an Angular 2 component which relies on a service call to populate the data. But, this service calls promise is handled inside another function.

```
this.data = null; //empty data is defined here.

public getDataMethod(){
    // controller related logic
    privateService.privateMethod(
        (data) => {this.data = data} //the data is populated here
    )
}
```

How can I wait for the inner function to resolve?

I read that we can wait for promises to resolve with 'done' but the only examples I found were of directly calling the promise. (Not a nested promise inside a function)

I tried passing the `done` method into the function and it works well.

```
public getDataMethod(done){
    // controller related logic
    privateService.privateMethod(
        (data) => {this.data = data} //the data is populated here
        done(); //Calling done when the promise is resolved. 
    )
}
```

But, that does muddy up the code that's tested. Is there a better way of waiting for the `data` value to populate before running the tests?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is all explained in the Angular docs testing section [Test a component with an async service](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-with-async-service). You basically have a couple options.

1. Use `async` to wrap the tests. Angular knows when there are asynchronous tasks happening, because it uses zones to monkey patch all the asynchronous functions like `setTimeout`. When we use `async`, Angular will prevent the test from completing until all the async tasks are out of the queue.

   ```
    import { async } from '@angular/core/testing';

    it('..', async(() => {
       // any async calls that happen between here
       // will be completed before the test completes
    }))
   ```

   the other part to this is waiting for async tasks to complete before we make any assertions. For that, we can use `fixture.whenStable()` which will wait before the async tasks to complete, then notify us with a promise

   ```
    it('..', async(() => {
       service.someAsyncTask();
       fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
         expect(...) 
       })
    }))
   ```
2. The other option is to use `fakeAsync/tick` combo. Angular allows us to wait for the async tasks to complete by calling `tick`. This allows us to make the test seem synchronous

   ```
    import { fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';

    it('..', fakeAsync(() => {
       service.someAsyncTask();
       tick();
       expect(...)
    }))
   ```